# A query on Palm Khintchine Theorem's proof

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

I was searching for a good reference on Palm Khintchine theorem proof. When I googled it, I got the following reference (as a Google book) [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=IcVlwPS0qCwC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=palm%20khintchine%20theorem%20proof&source=bl&ots=8q60PWVB1N&sig=Jipt80viV2T75Tfi0JTs_Q5jcWA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c-oEUpLWEIS04ASvoIDoCA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=palm%20khintchine%20theorem%20proof&f=false).

It states that a superposition of independent "low intensity" not necessarily Poisson processes (But Equilibrium Renewal processes), converges (I think it is a weak convergence) to a Poisson Process. The theorem, in a nutshell, justifies why we use Poisson Processes to model telephone traffic etc.

Now on page 157, the following statements are made:(Equation $5.74$)

$$P\left\{ N_{jm}(t) = 0\right\} = 1  - \lambda_{jm}t+\alpha_j\lambda_{jm}t\epsilon \quad (1)$$

Here $t\geq 0$, $0 \leq \alpha_j < 1 $ and $\epsilon > 0$.

But then he says, show that this implies
$$|\ln (P\left\{ N_{jm}(t) = 0\right\}) + \lambda_{jm} t| = |\ln \left(1  +\alpha_j\lambda_{jm}t\epsilon \right)| < \lambda_{jm}\epsilon c(t) \quad (2)$$
where $c(t)$ is a non -ve constant independent of $j$.

I am pretty sure the equality in $(2)$ is incorrect. However the inequality which follows from $\ln(1+x) \leq x$ and $\alpha_{j} < 1$ is correct (I think) since this is the key to the proof of Palm's theorem.

My question is how does one arrive at the inequality, since the equality in $(2)$ is incorrect?

I tried taking log on both sides of (1) and thus:

$$\ln (P\left\{ N_{jm}(t) = 0\right\})  = \ln(1  - \lambda_{jm}t+\alpha_j\lambda_{jm}t\epsilon)$$
$$\leq - \lambda_{jm}t+\alpha_j\lambda_{jm}t\epsilon$$
This is one half of the solution and I need the other half i.e. a similar lower bound.

I appreciate any hints on this. Thanks.

**Edit:** $N_{jm}(t)$ is an equilibrium renewal process.

Comment: @gautum Shenoy : Maybe theorem 16.18 of Kallenberg's book here does the trick :http://books.google.co.in/books?id=L6fhXh13OyMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=kallenberg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-WQGUovdNInD0QXaroCwAg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=kallenberg&f=false